# Causality between two binary time series

Tags: pandas, time-series, signals, heartbeat, autoregressive-models

I have the following sample of a big dataframe:

```
Time (ms)  Signal_1  Signal_2
0          0         0
1          0         0
2          0         1
3          0         0
4          1         0
5          0         0
6          0         0
.          .         .
.          .         .
.          .         .
996        1         1
997        0         0
998        0         0
```

**Signal_1** represents if occurred a heart beat in a person **X** in Time i.

**Signal_2** represents if occurred a heart beat in a person **Y** in Time i.

Time (ms) is the **Time i** and the index of the dataframe.
Time = 0 represents the begin of the experiment. Time = 1000 represents the first second passed after the begin of the experiment.

Since the signals are nominal (boolean), how can I use VAR and Granger Causality to say if Signal_1 causes Signal_2?
Is there any way to calculate correlation between these binary time series data?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like https://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be a better exchange to ask this question -- statistics rather than programming question

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful. I will post the question there too.

Comment: Given you understand the concepts behind vector autoregressions and Granger, the code is really simple. Use [`statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html) and [`statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests.html). The documentation is pretty clear and concise and has examples, shouldn't be of too much trouble. Now, if you need help with the theoretical approach for these methods, then `stats.stackexchange` is the place for this discussion.

Comment: Thanks! These references are really useful!